# Want to fill a <StackPanel> with ToggleButtons populated from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, togglebutton

I am a bit new to MVVM and i must say it is not easy...
As the topic saying want to populate a StackPanel with ToggleButtons populated from a Dictionary.
Can someone put my in the right direction ?

Greetings Fonzie

```
 public class Soort
    {
        public int ID;            
        public Boolean Pressed;
        public string shortTitle;
        public string Title;
        public SolidColorBrush BorderColor;            
        public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor;
        public int DefaultTime;           
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, Soort> dSoorten = new Dictionary<int, Soort>();
```

Comment: Use an ItemsControl. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would need a `ViewModel` first:

```
public class Soort
{
    public int ID;            
    public Boolean Pressed {get;set;} //Must be read/write a property to enable two way binding
    public string shortTitle;
    public string Title {get;}
    public SolidColorBrush BorderColor;            
    public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor;
    public int DefaultTime;           
}

public class SoortsViewModel
{
     public Dictionary<int, Soort> Soorts {get;}
}
```

Then bind it to a `ItemsControl` view:

```
<ItemsControl Source="{Binding Soorts.Values}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Checked="{Binding IsPressed, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you Andri, it cost me still a day to work but that was because i didn't follow your example right xD